# Server unresponsive when trying to exec a .bat file from a PHP script

Tags: php, batch-file

I have a .bat file located in the same folder as my php file named start.bat
I want the .bat file to execute when I click the submit button.

My php file is as shown:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo exec('start.bat');
echo "Done!";
} else {
// display the form
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Server">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

When I click the button the webpage goes to a never ending loop of "Waiting for server..."
And it wont run the batch file.

Is there something, like permissions i need to set so the batch file runs, or am i doing something wrong code wise?

Thanks for the quick help as i need to resolve this issue today!

Comment: Have you checked what the server is responding? You can use google chrome's network inspector to check the detail of the server responses and debug it more throughly.

Comment: Do you know which OS is used on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `echo` before `exec` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

First and as a good practice, you should always use absolute paths and not relative paths. The system might be looking for start.bat in another place. You will never know for sure where any automated call has its relative point. I could tell you some hilarious stores of wiped out system32 paths.

Second, exec() stands for executable. Depending on your systems setup a bat file may not be recognized as an executable. The .bat extension was used in the DOS times for batch files. Windows systems since Windows NT use .cmd.

In your Windows web server open a command prompt and type

```
set PATHEXT
```

There you should see .BAT. If this is set then the .bat should run with exec().

If you don't see .bat and as another good practice you can fire up the host first for a bat file which is cmd.

```
exec('cmd /c c:\www\start.bat');
```

You may also try system() instead of exec().

Comment: I tried all of that, and the server does have .bat.The server still acts the same way, just doing nothing and my browser saying "Waiting for server..."

Comment: Well, then is just one thing left to do. Show us the content of your start.bat file

Comment: When ran from the dedi it runs fine.